# Adding markers in a list and on map but not able to remove those markers from map while looping

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

Here is the code, how I am adding marker into the map:

```
markerOpt = new MarkerOptions();
markerOpt.SetTitle("Shop");
markerOpt.SetPosition(Location);
_map.AddMarker(markerOpt).ShowInfoWindow();
Marker aM = _map.AddMarker(markerOpt);
listCurrentPostsMarkers.Add(aM);
```

No problem while adding markers on map and to the list but not able to remove those markers on map. Here is code, how I am doing it.

```
foreach(Marker mk in listCurrentPostsMarkers)
{
   mk.Remove();
}
```

Here are the objects with its classes

```
List<Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Marker> listCurrentPostsMarkers
Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap _map
Android.Gms.Maps.Model.LatLng Location
```

I'm new here. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: You're adding the same marker twice (2 calls to AddMarker with same options) but adding the marker object once to the list.  So in the end it appears nothing happened because the duplicates are still visible.

Comment: how about this "listCurrentPostsMarkers.Add(_map.AddMarker(markerOpt));" ?? Its not working btw.

Comment: Again, you have 2 calls to .AddMarker() with the _same_ options - these will be 2 different markers to the map but they will be colocated and you only add the second one to the list - so only the second is removed leaving the identical first one on the map.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? I mean, please tell me the actual way or that particular line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code speaks louder than prose I guess:

```
markerOpt = new MarkerOptions();
markerOpt.SetTitle("Shop");
markerOpt.SetPosition(Location);
Marker aM = _map.AddMarker(markerOpt);
aM.ShowInfoWindow();
// you don't need this line (it creates a duplicate marker) ===> Marker aM = _map.AddMarker(markerOpt);
listCurrentPostsMarkers.Add(aM);
```

Comment: Alright then just remove that line (Marker aM = _map.AddMarker(markerOpt)) then "aM" is an object of what?

Comment: At this point, just copy-paste the code and see if it works.  If it does then stare at it and you may see the duplicates in the OP code.

Comment: first of all have some patience bro, look when you said that I was calling ".AddMarker" twice. So I deleted line "_map.AddMarker(markerOpt).ShowInfoWindow();" and did directly this "listCurrentPostsMarkers.Add(_map.AddMarker(markerOpt));". Now was only one ".AddMarker". That did not work. But now its working with "Marker aM = _map.AddMarker(markerOpt);" thanks. cheers and take a deep breath.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making two marker on each other !!!

```
_map.AddMarker(markerOpt).ShowInfoWindow(); //first one added here
Marker aM = _map.AddMarker(markerOpt); // second one added here
```

Later you only remove one of them and that is the reason why you still see one on the map.
Do what @Andy told you :

```
markerOpt = new MarkerOptions();
markerOpt.SetTitle("Shop");
markerOpt.SetPosition(Location);
Marker aM = _map.AddMarker(markerOpt);
aM.ShowInfoWindow();
listCurrentPostsMarkers.Add(aM);
```

Comment: You called it twice. ".AddMarker"